# A question about the reflection groups and root system.

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, root-systems

I am studing the book "Reflection groups and Coxeter groups" written by James E. Humphreys. On page 11, I am at a loss for the Theorem 1.5.[image]

I don't understand why $W'\beta \cap \Delta\neq \emptyset$  in $(2)$ can explain $\Pi \subset W'\Delta$ ?

I post my effort here.
For any $\beta \in \Pi$
$$\beta =s_{\alpha} (s_{\alpha}\beta), $$ we need only to show $s_{\alpha}\beta\subset \Delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
      &\, \text{for every $\beta \in \Pi$ : $W' \beta \cap \Delta \neq \emptyset$}                        \\
  \iff&\, \text{for every $\beta \in \Pi$ exists $w' \in W'$ with $w' \beta \in \Delta$}                  \\
  \iff&\, \text{for every $\beta \in \Pi$ exists $w' \in W'$ with $\beta \in (w')^{-1} \Delta$}           \\
  \iff&\, \text{for every $\beta \in \Pi$ exists $\tilde{w}' \in W'$ with $\beta \in \tilde{w}' \Delta$}  \\
  \iff&\, \text{for every $\beta \in \Pi$ : $\beta \in W' \Delta$}                                        \\
  \iff&\, \Pi \subseteq W' \Delta
\end{align*}

A bit less formal:
\begin{align*}
    &\, \text{for every $\beta \in \Pi$ : $W' \beta \cap \Delta$}
\\
\iff&\, \text{the $W'$-orbit of every $\beta \in \Pi$ contains some $\alpha \in \Delta$}
\\
\iff&\, \text{every $\beta \in \Pi$ is contained in the $W'$-orbit of some $\alpha \in \Delta$}
\\
\iff&\, \Pi \subseteq W' \Delta
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much, In this book,  in order to explain your first equivalence,  the auther post this Theorem. So we can't use this fact to explain this Theorem.

Comment: I don’t understand your objection: The equivalence transformations do not depend on any statements from the book, I am simply rewritting the given statement. The inital statement, that $\forall \beta \in \Pi: W' \beta \cap \Delta$, has already been proven in part (1) of the proof.

Comment: @ Jendrik Stelzner , I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Having proved $W'\beta\cap \Delta\neq\emptyset$ for any $\beta\in \Pi$ we have the following argument:

Let $\beta\in\Pi$. There exists $w\in W'$ such that $w\beta=\alpha\in\Delta$. Now, $w^{-1}\in W'$ and $\beta=w^{-1}\alpha\in W'\Delta$. It follows that $\Pi\subset W'\Delta$.